# ¿Cómo agregar código de dialogflow messenger a un componente en angular?

Tags: html, angular, dialogflow

Deseo agregar un chatbot que hice en Dialogflow a mi página web creada en Angular. Para esto el framework de Dialogflow me permite integrar el chatbot a mi página sin problema alguno proporcionándome el código necesario como lo vemos a continuación (aquí omito los valores que me da):

### src\index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cinvesbot</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<!-- Código que me proporciona Dialogflow -->
<script src="..."></script>
<df-messenger
  intent="..."
  chat-title="..."
  agent-id="..."
  language-code="es"
></df-messenger>
<!-- Termina aquí el código de Dialogflow -->
</body>
</html>
```

Esto funciona perfecto. Desde **`index.html`** puedo acceder al chatbot que hice en Dialogflow, pero el problema es el siguiente. La página de **`index.html`** sirve para iniciar sesión, como se puede apreciar en la siguiente captura.

[image: Login]

No es correcto que se muestre ahí. Lo ideal es que cuando el usuario inicia sesión aparece un Dashborad y ahí es dónde quiero que se muestre.

Yo tengo un componente que se llama **`dashboard.component.html`** y si ahí pongo el código que me da Dialogflow me marca error.

[image: Dashboard]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo **`dashboard.component.ts`** tengo lo siguiente:

### dashboard.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
})
```

Según leí que si utilizo `template` y pongo el código ahí debería funcionar. Pero no sé si se pueden poner al mismo tiempo `template` y `templateUrl`. Aquí dejo cómo lo estaría poniendo:

### dashboard.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  template:`
  <script src="..."></script>
<df-messenger
  intent="..."
  chat-title="..."
  agent-id="..."
  language-code="es"
></df-messenger>
  `,
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
})
```

No sale ningún error, pero tampoco me muestra el chatbot en mi `dashboard.component.html`.

¿Cómo podría solucionar mi problema?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el módulo al que pertenece ese componente se debe agregar `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`, si fuera el `app.module` se vería así:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      ...,
  declarations: ...,
  bootstrap:    ...,
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

El `<script>` debe quedar siempre en el `index.html` y el `<df-messenger>` se coloca en el componente.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias Lobos. Ya no sale ningún error y el chatbot me aparece en el dashboard como lo requería. Solo agregaría que se debe de poner `import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';`